# Stripe payments popup internalization

Tags: internationalization, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe custom popup form for payment.

[payment popup demo](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom)

It's great, however my site is not in English, so i want the popup to change the language of labels. Is it possible?

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not yet possible to localize `Stripe Checkout` and if that's something you really need, you should design your own form and use [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) for the token generation.